# Where clause with varbinary type doesn't work

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table MyTable with a field MyField, which is varbinary(max). I have the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable WHERE MyField IS NOT NULL
```

The SELECT clause can have anything, it does not matter. Because of the varbinary MyField in the Where clause, the execution never ends.

I tried even this:

```
SELECT Size
FROM
(
    SELECT ISNULL(DATALENGTH(MyField), 0) AS Size FROM MyTable
) AS A
WHERE A.Size > 0
```

The inner query works fine, the whole query without the Where clause works fine, but with that Where clause it is stuck. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Is it possible the query is blocked by another query?  Right click the database and choose "Activity Monitor" to check.

Comment: I have a database using a varbinary(max) field to hold raw images.  I use the query you gave in your first example and never have an issue. Are you sure you aren't omitting anything?

Comment: What does the estimated execution plan shows?. Obviously, an actual execution plan would be better, but since the execution never ends....

Comment: @ Andomar I don't think so, because as I said, I can successfully run parts of the query, and only the where clause causes the trouble.

Comment: @Jeff Reddy I cannot see what may be missing.

Comment: @Lamak The estimated execution plan does not show up...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't think or assume that it couldn't possibly be blocking, just because a different query returns immediately. With a different where clause, and a different plan, and possibly different locking escalation, you could certainly have cases where one query is blocked and another isn't, even against the same table.

The query is obviously being blocked, if your definition of "stuck" is what I think it is. Now you just need to determine by who.

***In one query window***, do this:

```
SELECT @@SPID;
```

Make note of that number. Now ***in that same query window***, run your query that gets "stuck" (in other words, don't select a spid in one window and expect it to have anything to do with your query that is already running in another window).

Then, ***in a different query window***, do this:

```
SELECT blocking_session_id, status, command, wait_type, last_wait_type 
  FROM sys.dm_exec_requests 
  WHERE session_id = <spid from above>;
```

Here is a visualization that I suspect might help (note that my "stuck" query is different from yours):

> [image: click to embiggen]

If you get a non-zero number in the first column, then ***in that different query window***, do this:

```
DBCC INPUTBUFFER(<that blocking session id>);
```

If you aren't blocked, I'd be curious to know what the other columns show.

---

As an aside, changing the `WHERE` clause to use slightly different predicates to identify the same rows isn't going to magically eliminate blocking. Also, there is no real benefit to doing this:

```
SELECT Size
FROM
(
    SELECT ISNULL(DATALENGTH(MyField), 0) AS Size FROM MyTable
) AS A
WHERE A.Size > 0
```

When you can just do this:

```
SELECT ISNULL(DATALENGTH(MyField), 0) AS Size 
  FROM dbo.MyTable -- always use schema prefix
  WHERE DATALENGTH(MyField) > 0; -- always use semi-colon
```

SQL Server is smart enough to not calculate the `DATALENGTH` twice, if that is your concern.

Comment: The select from  sys.dm_exec_requests  returned nothing.

Comment: @David then either your query isn't still running, or you entered the wrong spid.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know. The query looks like still running, and it is hard to make a mistake with the id. I checked it. 
Also, the query that selects size is not the real one, I just tried to narrow down the problem, that is why it may look silly. :)

Comment: @David Sorry, I don't know how to further help you if I don't know what you're doing wrong. If a query is still running from session_id 58, then they will have at least one row in sys.dm_exec_requests under that session_id. So not sure if you pulled the spid from the wrong window or what, but I can't really fix that if you're sure and you checked. *shrug*

Comment: Why 58? And you mentioned wrong window. Which window is right?

Comment: @David I was just using 58 *as an example*. I have no possible way of ever knowing or even guessing what session_id you got in your query windows. I thought the instructions were pretty clear, but let me make them more so.

Comment: Execute [this](http://sqlserverplanet.com/dba/a-better-sp_who2-using-dmvs-sp_who3) then tell me what it says then maybe we can help you.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand For some reason, it started working now. I mean, the query... Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @DavidShochet that doesn't mean you don't have a bigger problem! Do not I repeat **DO NOT** mistake something mysteriously working for a solution.

Comment: Start buying stock in magic companies? At the very least, now you have a method to track down the problem next time (you just need to follow the directions correctly, and make sure that the query is actually still "stuck" when you try to check what it's stuck on).

Comment: @DavidShochet I would recommend using using the stored procedure I linked to get and idea of what's going on with your server during a slow down or lag. Right now all evidence points to something else is blocking your query which means it will probably happen again. Use SP_who3 so see what's happening on your server during these times.

Answer (score 5):

Just for fun and giggles I decided to toss this one out to you. I'm taking some things for granted here but you can look at tasks that had to wait. Look for wait types that begin with `LCK_` as these will be your blocked tasks. Please note that on a busy server the ring buffer may have rolled over after a while. Also note that this is intended to supplement @AaronBertran's excellent answer and in no way meant to supplant it. His is more comprehensive and is the correct way to identify the issue while it's happening.

```
        SELECT 
            td.r.value('@name','sysname') event_name,
            td.r.value('@timestamp','datetime2(0)') event_timestamp, 
            td.r.value('(data[@name="wait_type"]/text)[1]','sysname') wait_type,
            td.r.value('(data[@name="duration"]/value)[1]','bigint') wait_duration,
            td.r.value('(action[@name="sql_text"]/value)[1]','nvarchar(max)') sql_text,
            td.r.query('.') event_data
        FROM (
                    SELECT
                    CAST(target_data AS XML) target_data
                    FROM sys.dm_xe_sessions s
                    JOIN sys.dm_xe_session_targets t
                        ON s.address = t.event_session_address

                    WHERE s.name = N'system_health'
                        and target_name = 'ring_buffer'
                    ) base
        CROSS APPLY target_data.nodes('/RingBufferTarget/*') td(r)
        where td.r.value('@name','sysname') = 'wait_info';
```